# Getting specific part of value in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, I am sorry if I sound pretty newby about this, I am actually an UX Researcher, that is currently working on some front-end project that requeres some backend developing. Since there is no backend dev, I have to do it myself.

Currently I am trying to get a specific part of this string in the value:

meta_key: `links`

meta_value: `a:2:{s:3:"url";s:26:"https://YOURLINK.COM/LINKMEHARD";s:5:"title";s:4:"Film";}`

What I need to call in php is the value of s:26 (the link). I would have tried to find out that myself, hut I have no idea how that term of the value in the value is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "meta_value" string that you have provided is actually serialized PHP (http://php.net/serialize).

You can simply take the value that you have retrieved from the database and call unserialize() on it to turn it back into an object or array.

From what you've provided, you should be able to do something like:

```
$unserialized = unserialize($row['meta_value']);
echo $unserialized['url']; // should produce "https://YOURLINK.COM/LINKMEHARD"
```